# Teradata - highly skewed query

Tags: teradata, data-warehouse

I am presently facing skewness issue while loading a fact table with `Insert into ... Select` from clause.

I have a staging-source tables defined with a `NO PI` & for now I have defined a fact table with `PI` on `Report_Id`. `PI` defined on `Report_Id` considering I will be loading data for other reports in furture, that is for sure.

However, in `DBA` perspective, the query is highly skewed. 
Can you please suggest whether should I define a `NOPI` fact table or define `UPI` fact table. In case of `UPI` table, what should be the `UPI` key ? `Identity Id` ?

Please advise.

Many thanks,

Comment: There is no way we can tell you what column to use for your primary key.  Nor, based on what you've told us, can we even tell you which table is causing the skew.  Here is some information from Teradata on [choosing a column for your PI](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1094_111A/ch09.050.166.html).

Comment: Identity as a NPI should work better. I've read a few white papers stating that a fixed-column PI on a distributed database system may be a hot cause of storage skew.

Comment: Can you provide the target table DDL and the entire INSERT statement?

Comment: Hi @RobPaller, the issue was concerned with the PI of the table. I had selected a single value column, ReportId as a PI which causing skewness. So at present I have added an identity column & made it a UPI. Is this fine considering a IDENTITY column as UPI ?

Comment: Then the skew was based on a poor PI selection. Another column to even out the distribution or a surrogate is necessary. Adding the identity column provided you a surrogate and including the original column is not necessary. Joins on the natural column may still cause skew because the spool file will likely be hash distributed by this column, if the value that has a high cardinality is included in the resulting spool file. Statistics in this column may be necessary. Of